# Sysdate as char instead of date

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a query.

i have a config table AB where a row is marked as "sysdate-360"

```
col1 ||col2
AB   || sysdate-360
BC   || sysdate -2
```

When i write a procedure to get date value from the config table AB i used.

```
    v_date varchar(20);
    cursor c1 as
    select col2 from AB;
    then 

    for ab_date in c1
    loop
    select ab_date.col2 into v_date from dual;
v_sql := 'delete from any_table where load_date <='||v_date;
execute immediate v_sql ;
commit;
    end loop;
```

The procedure is compiled but when i execute I'm getting below error

ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-06512: at "procedure", line 46
ORA-06512: at line 1
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:
*Action:

The sysdate -360 is considered as char but not as date since SYSDATE is itself a date right?

Please help.

Comment: Presumably `load_date` is a date type. Your obfuscation is confusing things a bit as your cursor query doesn't look right - is it really `from config_table where col1 = AB`? and you haven't indicated which line corresponds to line 46 in the error. What data type is `col1`, as you've made it look like a varchar? If it is a string, is `AB` a number, and you aren't enclosing it in quotes, and there are `col1` values that are *not* numbers? I think the error is from the cursor query, and nothing to do with the date....

Comment: I think you should get debug on the value in `v_sql` that you pass to `execute immediate`.  This will likely reveal your problem, such as a missing space in `v_sql`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you handle only expressions `SYSDATE +/- N` I'd suggest to modify the config table as follows

```
ID SYSDATE_OFFSET
-- --------------
AB           -360 
BC             -2
```

So you have a numeric offset to sysdate which can be queried this way:

```
select sysdate + (select SYSDATE_OFFSET from config where id = 'AB') s_360
from dual;

S_360           
-----------------
25.02.16 21:46:50
```

So you may open a cursor with the query above.

If you can't change the table - define a view that removes the string `sysdate` and converts to number!

Comment: let me check this i can change the config table.

Comment: I have another problem now.
my v_sql is giving proper query now but when i run this in execute immediate it is giving me below error.

00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"
*Cause: identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
           letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
           character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
           any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
           (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
           delimiters.

Comment: @AmjathAK using the new config you don't need to use execute immediate at all. Pass the offset in the DELTE as bind variable.

Comment: I have to find the partition name for my table so everything is written in v_sql including the dates.

so my delete query for v_sql is 

delete from my_table partition (partitionname) where load_date <= '01-FEB-2016';

So v_sql should have execute immediate, right?

Comment: To follow @MarmiteBomber's suggestion you would add a column to your cursor as `sysdate - ab.sysdate_offset as maxdate`, and then your delete statement will be something like `delete sometable t where t.load_date < ab_date.maxdate`. No need for dynamic SQL. What is the requirement around partitioning though?

Answer (score 2):

This looks quite fine to me. But why do you select into `v_date`? You get a string from the cursor which you can concatenate directly:

```
for ab_date in c1 loop
  v_sql := 'delete from any_table where load_date <=' || ab_date.col2;
  execute immediate v_sql ;
  commit;
end loop;
```

At last this is simply the concatanation of two strings `'delete from any_table where load_date <='` and `'sysdate-360'` which makes `'delete from any_table where load_date <= sysdate-360'` - exactly the SQL string you want.

(That would look even better with a proper column name such as `date_expression` instead of `col2`.)

More elaborate explanation: The cursor gets you the string 'sysdate-360'. The query `select ab_date.col2 into v_date from dual;` is simply `v_date := ab_date.col2;`. But is `v_date` a string? If not, you get a conversion error, because 'sysdate-360' is just a string, nothing more. If you expect the DBMS to see that the string contains 'sysdate' which also happens to be the name of a system variable for the current time and then convert this magically, you expect to much.

Comment: yes my 'sysdate-360" is considered as string, v_date is date defined. How to make dbms to see ssydate as system defined instead of a string.

Comment: As you are using it to build an SQL *string*, you don't need to do anything. Doesn't my script work for you?

Answer (score -1):

Try the to_date function

```
TO_DATE(v_date)
```

Comment: hope you read my question well. i have a cursor which reads data, teh column contains the "sysdate-360" is read as char instead of date

Comment: what type has col2? I didn't see your procedure first. Would you format it as code?